# How to configure swagger with laravel passport

Tags: laravel, swagger, laravel-passport

I'm generating rest api documentation and the tool I'm using is swagger. I've configured l5-swagger package for this. unfortunately i'm not getting the authorize option from the ui. my l5-swagger.php file

```
'passport' => [ 
                'type' => 'oauth2',
                'description' => 'Laravel passport oauth2 security.',
                'in' => 'header',
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'flows' => [
                    "password" => [
                      "authorizationUrl" => config('app.url') . '/oauth/authorize',
                      "tokenUrl" => config('app.url') . '/oauth/token',
                      "refreshUrl" => config('app.url') . 'oauth/token/refresh',
                      "scopes" => []
                           ],
                      ],
             ],
```

My Controller looks like this

```
/**
 * @OA\GET(
 ** path="/api/product/{product_id}",
 *   tags={"Product"},
 *   security={
 *    {
 *     "passport": {}},
 *    },
 *   summary="Product Detail",
 *   operationId="productdetails",
 *   @OA\Parameter(
 *      name="product_id",
 *      in="path",
 *      required=true,
 *      @OA\Schema(
 *           type="integer"
 *      )
 *   ),
 *   @OA\Response(
 *      response=200,
 *       description="Success",
 *      @OA\MediaType(
 *          mediaType="application/json",
 *      )
 *   ),
 *)
  public function get_product($product_id){
 
  }
```

i'm not sure what I'm missing that's causing the disappearing of authorize lock button

[image: reference image]

Comment: Clear your cache and config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing your own security There is 'securitySchemes' => []  find passport array  just uncomment that and replace the dummy oauth url with the real one's and all set.